# In ggplot2, I am looking for how to highlight, using legends above the bars of a chart, differences between categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, categories, tukey

A chart that relates continuous variables to discrete variables revealed differences between groups. I need to highlight which categories are the same and different in a straightforward and simple way.

To do this, I need to label with the same letters the categories that are not different and with different letters those that were different.

```
plot_concentration <- ggplot(tabmean_con, aes(x = time, y = concentration, "color" = "2", "6")) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = concentration - se, ymax = concentration + se),
    width = 0.1
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = tabmean_con, aes(x = time, y = concentration),
    col = "black", size = 3
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(y = concentration + se, label = ""),
    col = "black",
    size = 4, vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0.4
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "hours",
    y = "nectar concentration ( % brix)",
    title = "Nectar concentration"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = positions) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.position = c(0.3, 0.8)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30))
```

I tried this code above, where the data set is `tabmean_con`, which is an object I created using the `summarySE()` function from the `Rmisc` package.

In the first layer after the `color` argument, '2' and '6' are the y-axis categories that are the same and I would like to color them differently from the others. However I need to put letters on them to differentiate them. according to the result of Tukey's post hoc test, which indicates between which groups there are differences after an ANOVA